# Icarus Verilog simulation : Scope index expression is not constant: i

Tags: verilog, icarus

I am simulating a 16 bit MIPS netlist in Icarus Verilog.
This is the error i get in testbench

```
mips_16_core_top_tb_0.v:144: error: Scope index expression is not constant: i
mips_16_core_top_tb_0.v:144: error: Unable to bind wire/reg/memory `uut.register_file_inst.reg_array[i]' in `mips_16_core_top_tb_0_v.display_all_regs'

Related code : 
task display_all_regs;
begin
$display("display_all_regs:");
$display("------------------------------");
$display("R0\tR1\tR2\tR3\tR4\tR5\tR6\tR7");
for(i=0; i<8; i=i+1)
$write("%d\t",uut.register_file_inst.reg_array[i]); <--- error points to this line

$display("\n------------------------------");
end
endtask
```

I do get this same error when i simulate the RTL too but i still get the vcd file dumped out.In case of the netlist,I dont even get the vcd file generated.
Would be glad to hear your thoughts.

Comment: How is `reg_array` defined? Please define `integer i;` within the task. There might be conflicting drivers to the same `i`.

Comment: tried adding integer i; it says syntax error at line integer i;

Error
mips_16_core_top_tb_0.v:140: syntax error
mips_16_core_top_tb_0.v:140: error: malformed statement

Comment: Move `integer i;` before `begin`. You cannot attach the file here directly. You can upload it to a file sharing site with public access (or your own personal site) and provide the link.

Comment: If reg_array isn't defined how do you expect to write out its contents? Have you verified that the hierarchical path to the register values is the same in the netlist as it is in the RTL?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.
The reg_array is a register declared in register_file.v.It is not an input/output port.Is this a syntactically correct way to call a signal that is not a part of the port declaration list?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks fine, and I've just tested cross-module variable indexing of arrays in Icarus (the current version, from git) and it works.

I suspect your problem is that you're compiling `mips_16_core_top_tb_0.v` by itself - Icarus will give this message if you do. All source files need to be compiled together in Icarus. Some other simulators will allow you to compile this file by itself, and then only check for errors during elaboration (ie. when you run the simulation), but the way Icarus does it is how Verilog was originally intended to be used.

Comment: What do you mean by compiling by itself and source files needing to be compiled together?.Are you saying i should mention the file names altogether at run time.Sorry I am kinda newbie.

Comment: I have Icarus version 9.5,one previous to the current

Comment: Run your compile command as `iverilog file1.v file2.v .... filen.v`, ie. put *all* your source files on the `iverilog` command line. This gives you an executable, called `a.out` or something similar. `iverilog` needs to see all the source files at once to check for errors and produce an executable. Verilog doesn't have a specification for 'compile one file at a time and link and check for other errors later', like some languages. However, some vendors have done this anyway. In other words, those vendors would let you compile 'one at a time', but Icarus doesn't.

Comment: I have got a solution for that ,Can you take a look at this when you get a chance?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18422889/gate-level-simulation-of-mips

Answer (score 0):

Your index in register[index] must be constant in this situation. In reg_array[i], i is a variable and not fixed. To simulate using this code you must remodel the design so that it doesn't require a variable indexed register. It may be a simulator-specific lack of support for this feature. If that is the case, you should try a different simulator.

Comment: Have changed the indexed value to a number,still i get the same error.Should i declare the reg-array in the port list?.

Comment: Hmm when you say number do you mean a constant like the number "0"? The error doesn't look related to port declarations. If you can provide a minimum sized compileable example of the problem I'm sure I can be more helpful.